# jQuery-UI Dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using this code sample that came from jquery-ui website to show the dialog form.
How can I add functionality to the "OK" button. I want this button to invoke a javascript function "PageValidation", and if it returned true, then call a C# function that will save the data in the db, and then close the modal form. If "PageValidation returned false then do nothing and don't close the modal form.

This is the code:

```
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    }, 
                    "Cancel": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: is it a "normal" asp.net page or a mvc page?

Comment: ok, then it should work like in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your function in the "OK" function like this:

```
                "Ok": function() { 
                    MyFunc();
                    $(this).dialog("close"); 
                },
```

then, write the body of MyFunc() , like this:

```
function MyFunc(){
     if (PageValidation())
           AjaxCSharpCall();
}
```

and finally write the body of AjaxCSharpCall() to send an ajax request to a page, in which you can do your C# function. something like this:

```
function AjaxCSharpCall()    {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "MyPage.aspx",
       data: "doFunction=True",
       success: function(){
         alert( "C# Function was executed!" );
       }
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does AjaxCSharpCall() do? TY.

Comment: You have to make an Ajax request in it to a page. It is just like a real HTTP request, but without refreshing the page. you send the request and at the server, on that particular page, you do your c# function. Do you know Ajax?

Comment: I know just a liitle bit ajax.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can see a sample of that function body.

Comment: ajax tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

, ajax on jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

just make a button (hyperlink) with that functionality and copy the javascript command from the button to the "Ok" event from your dialog. now you can delete your button and use it with your dialog

you javascript should look like that:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$OverallMainContent$MainContent$Your_Control','yourFuncOnServer')
```

just try adding a button as a hyperlink and copy it

Answer (score 0):

Write your `OK` something like this:

```
"OK": function() {
    saveData();
}
```

Then write `saveData()` something like this:

```
function saveData() {
   if (pageValidation()) {
     /* C# function here. */
     $("#dialog").dialog('close');
   }
}
```

Hope that helps :)