# jQuery-UI Dialog 2

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Please take a look at the question I asked not so long ago: [jQuery-UI Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729554/jquery-ui-dialog)
Please look at the question I marked as the correct one.

The problem I have now is that I don't know exactly in the aspx page how to access the data from the ajax call. 
Can I call the Save method on my page(c#) directly?
How do I send the parameters to be saved?
My ajax call looks like this now:

```
        function AjaxSavePayment() 
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Payments.aspx",
                data: "doFunction=True",
                success: function () {alert("C# Function was executed!");}

            });
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PageMethods instead.

```
        function AjaxSavePayment() 
        {

            var rdCash = document.getElementById("<%= rdCash.ClientID %>").checked;
            var rdCCard = document.getElementById("<%= rdCCard.ClientID %>").checked;
            var rdCheck = document.getElementById("<%= rdCheck.ClientID %>").checked; 
            var txtAmountCash = document.getElementById("<%= txtAmountCash.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtCCardNumber = document.getElementById("<%= txtCCardNumber.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtCCardExpMonth = document.getElementById("<%= txtCCardExpMonth.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtCCardExpYear = document.getElementById("<%= txtCCardExpYear.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtAmountCCard = document.getElementById("<%= txtAmountCCard.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtCheckNumber = document.getElementById("<%= txtCheckNumber.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtCheckDate = document.getElementById("<%= txtCheckDate.ClientID %>").value;
            var txtAmountCheck = document.getElementById("<%= txtAmountCheck.ClientID %>").value;

            var drpCCardCompany = document.getElementById("<%= drpCCardCompany.ClientID %>").value;
            var MemberID = GetQueryVariable("MemberID");
            var ShulID = '<%=Session["ShulID"]%>';
            var PayTwardsPledgeID = "";
            PayTwardsPledgeID = GetQueryVariable("PayTwardsPledgeID");

            var PaymentMethod = "";
            if (rdCash) 
            {
                PaymentMethod = "Cash";
            }
            if (rdCCard) {
                PaymentMethod = "CCard";
            }
            if (rdCheck) {
                PaymentMethod = "Check";
            }

            PageMethods.SavePaymentWeb(ShulID, MemberID, PaymentMethod, txtAmountCash, txtAmountCCard
                                      , txtAmountCheck, txtCCardNumber, txtCCardExpMonth, txtCCardExpYear
                                      , txtCheckNumber, txtCheckDate, drpCCardCompany, PayTwardsPledgeID, OnSuccess);
            });
        }
```